# From AttributeType::Enum in Model to a matching selectField?

Tags: templating, plugin-development, models

So I have a model with an Enum and I want a selectField for that Enum. Is there a DRY way to do that ? And if yes does it work with the translation-filter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upcoming Craft 2.2 release added a getConstants() method to the [BaseEnum](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/enums/BaseEnum) class so you'd be able to do:

```
EnumClass::getConstants()
```

to get an array of all of the options in an enum.

Comment: Any info when it'll be available ?

Comment: Very soon now...